# R - solve_LSAP clue package how to write results in txt file?

Tags: r, class, variable-assignment

I am using solve_LSAP hungarian/munkres algorithm for an assignment problem from the clue package in R. I need to run several different assigmment problems and I would like to save them in separate txt file (or any type of file if possible) in a for loop for some subsequent processing required by the problem I have. I was wondering if/how I can do that.

I currently use the following code:

```
y <- solve_LSAP(costMatrix, maximum = TRUE)
str(y)
```

It is a Class "solve_LSAP" object and when i want to write it in a txt file it does not allow me. It gives the "cannot coerce class ""solve_LSAP"" error.

How can I solve this problem and write class object in a file in R? Could not seem to find any solution here so far.

Thanks for help.

Comment: `dput(y, "results.txt")`?

Comment: another alternative .. `capture.output(y, file="results.txt")`

Comment: @Marek I am not sure why I get the same error(cannot coerce error) with dput function, i found that function earlier on search as well.

Comment: Though capture.output works. Thanks @user20650.

Comment: How to get the outputs of this function programmatically? I'm having trouble interacting with the outputs. Let's say I want to get the best assignment for the first entry, how can this class be indexed?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
sol

Optimal assignment:
1 => 3, 2 => 13, 3 => 2, 4 => 6, 5 => 9, 6 => 7, 7 => 14, 8 => 10,
9 => 15, 10 => 16, 11 => 12

class(sol)

[1] "solve_LSAP"

length(sol)

[1] 11

sink("results.txt", append=TRUE)
for (i in 1:length(sol)){
    cat(sprintf("%i\n", sol[i]))
}
sink()
```

Comment: Could you please format your post? It is pretty unreadeable right now.